# Getting dimension of specific segment window

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing

I'm working on comparing the center of the blob with the 20% small box positioned at the center of the blob's bounding box.
I implemented this code first, to find the blob center points:

```
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
  For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
    If bmp.Point(x, y) = vbWhite 
      Then 
        Xs = Xs + x
        Ys = Ys + y
        area = area + 1
    endIF
  Next x
Next y
YCenteroid = Ys / area
XCentroid = Xs / area
```

Then, the width and the height of the blob is calculated as below:

```
BlobHeight = MaxY - MinY 
BlobWidth = MaxX - MinX
```

How to get that small box dimensions for comparing it with the center points?

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to define small box centered about (XCenteroid, YCenteroid) ?

Comment: Yes, that's my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordinates of small box centered about (XCenteroid, YCenteroid) with width = 20% of blob width

```
RectLeft = XCentroid - 0.1 * BlobWidth 
RectRight = XCentroid + 0.1 * BlobWidth 

RectTop = YCentroid - 0.1 * BlobHeight 
RectBottom = YCentroid + 0.1 * BlobHeight
```